# Настройка пробелов в twig

Tags: php, symfony2, twig

Подскажите, как можно настроить `twig`, что бы не было пробелов и пустой строки в тегах. Использовать {%**-** **-**%} надо для каждой строки, а `spaceless` убирает пробелы только между тегами, а в самих тегах, если есть табуляция в коде, происходит следующее:

```
<p>"
         text"</p>
```

Есть ли возможность настроить twig так, что бы не было пробелов?

P.S. Проект написан на Symfony2.

Comment: Нету, только работа с каждым тегом. "Не было" пишется раздельно.

Comment: тогда как можно избавиться от пробелов в twig?

Comment: Написать свой фильтр

Comment: Только работой с каждым тэгом. Но это HTML, вы что-то неправильно делаете, если оно вам меашет внутри блочных элементов. Ну, можно еще вообще весь вывод фильтровать и минифицировать.

Comment: минифицирование вывода это задача сервера, или можно средствами symfony2 минимизировать?

Comment: Вам верстку надо менять, а не минифицировать. Symfony2 и есть серверное приложение, нет? https://github.com/MatTheCat/HtmlCompressorBundle

Comment: Да, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{ var }} - "  some"

{{ var | trim }} - "some"

Подробнее - документация TWIG: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/trim.html

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky. Да, с удовольствием. Это из документации: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/trim.html. Там есть развернутый пример.

Comment: Спасибо! На Stack Overflow сообщество ожидает увидеть развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополненные ссылкой на источник. Мы считаем, что ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.